# how to make a see more button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make it there are 3 images and when I click on see more button it will show 4 images.
I have made html, css and javascript, but the image that is immediately displayed is 4. which should display 3 and when clicked see more will display 4 images.
so there are many pictures, but only 3 pictures are displayed, and when you click the see more button it will display other pictures

```js
 let loadMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.load-more');
    let currentItem = 3;

    loadMoreBtn.onclick = () =>{
    let boxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.container .hobby-list .hobby')];
    for (var i = currentItem; i < currentItem + 3; i++){
      boxes[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
    currentItem += 3;

    if(currentItem >= boxes.length){
      loadMoreBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#Hobby{
    padding: 50px 0;
}
.hobby-list{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 40px;
}
.hobby{
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.hobby img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.layer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6), #31c48d);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}

.layer a{
    margin-top: 15px;
    color: #31c48d;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Hobby">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hobby-list">
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="Assets/hobby_1.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing soccer</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="Assets/hobby_2.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing game</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="Assets/hobby_3.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing basketball</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="Assets/hobby_4.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Painting</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="load-more">See more</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add class `display: none` to the image you donot want to display at first load

See the code below
the logic to show the image on see more button was also not correct so I have changed that also

```js
let loadMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.load-more');
    let currentItem = 3;

    loadMoreBtn.onclick = () =>{
    let boxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.container .hobby-list .hobby')];
    for (var i = currentItem; i < boxes.length; i++){
      boxes[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
    currentItem += 3;

    if(currentItem >= boxes.length){
      loadMoreBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#Hobby{
    padding: 50px 0;
}
.hobby-list{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 40px;
}
.hobby{
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.hobby img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.layer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6), #31c48d);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}

.layer a{
    margin-top: 15px;
    color: #31c48d;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.display-none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Hobby">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hobby-list">
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="Assets/hobby_1.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing soccer</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="Assets/hobby_2.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing game</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="Assets/hobby_3.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing basketball</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby display-none">
                <img src="Assets/hobby_4.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Painting</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="load-more">See more</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hide* first the image you don't want to show and add make it visible once user click the button to *See more*.

```js
function loadMore() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreImage = document.getElementById("more");
  var loadBtn = document.getElementById("load-more");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    loadBtn.innerHTML = "See more"; 
    moreImage.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    loadBtn.innerHTML = "See less"; 
    moreImage.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
#Hobby{
   padding: 50px 0;
}
.hobby-list{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
   grid-gap: 40px;
}
.hobby{
   border-radius: 10px;
   position: relative;
}
.hobby img{
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 10px;
   display: block;
   transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.layer{
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6), #31c48d);
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   padding: 0 40px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 14px;
   transition: height 0.5s;
}

.layer a{
   margin-top: 15px;
   color: #31c48d;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 60px;
   background: #fff;
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   text-align: center;
}

.display-none {
   display: none;
}
#more {
   display: none;
}
#dots{
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 32px;
}
#load-more{
   height: 30px;
   width: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: gray;
}
#load-more:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="Hobby">
   <div class="container">
         <div class="hobby-list">
            <div class="hobby">
               <img src="Assets/hobby_1.png">
                     <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing soccer</h3><br>
                     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
               <img src="Assets/hobby_2.png">
                     <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing game</h3><br>
                     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
               <img src="Assets/hobby_3.png">
                     <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing basketball</h3><br>
                     </div>
            </div>
            <span id="dots">&#187;</span>
            <span id="more">
               <div class="hobby">
                  <img src="Assets/hobby_4.png">
                     <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Painting</h3><br>
                     </div>
               </div>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div onclick="loadMore()" class="load-more" id="load-more">See more</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First we need to add `display: none` to all the images on css, then we display only the 3 first images on load, then whenever we click on load button we show an image starting from the 4th.

```js
let loadMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.load-more');
let currentItem = 3;

let boxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.container .hobby-list .hobby')];
for (var i = 0; i < currentItem; i++) {
   boxes[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
}

loadMoreBtn.onclick = () => {
    boxes[currentItem].style.display = 'inline-block';
    currentItem += 1;
    if(currentItem >= boxes.length){
      loadMoreBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#Hobby{
    padding: 50px 0;
}
.hobby-list{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 40px;
}
.hobby{
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display:none;
}
.hobby img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.layer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6), #31c48d);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}

.layer a{
    margin-top: 15px;
    color: #31c48d;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Hobby">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hobby-list">
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing soccer</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing game</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Playing basketball</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Painting</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby">
                <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png">
                    <div class="layer">
                        <h3>Testing</h3><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="load-more">See more</div>
    </div>
</div>
```